# Directory Failed to Open on osm2pgrouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I'm trying to import osm data using osm2pgrouting, the process is stop during parsing data which given this error notification:

> Error Opening "D:/mydir/data.osm":No such file or directory failed to open/ parse data file "D:/mydir/data.osm

I have run my command as administrator, refer to the open issues at pgrouting git I add `--clean` command

This is the query I used to import the osm data:

```
osm2pgrouting.exe -d pgr -U username -W password -h localhost -p 5432 --clean -c mapconfig_for_cars.xml -f "D:\mydir\data.osm"
```

Comment: try with an absolute path

Comment: I've tried using the absolute path, but still it gives me those notification